# Websocket and playframework 2.0 in a multiserver environment

Tags: winforms, websocket, powershell-2.0

We're using playframework for our application in a distributed environment (ie app running on multiple servers) and I was wondering if it is possible to use websockets. If it is possible how would it be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but a websocket is bound to the same server throughout the life of the connection, it cannot move between servers, so if you need it to you will have to close it and open a new one that might go to a new server in some interval.